# how to delete file based on name length

Tags: java

I have a list of files with same suffix ,  the name of files contain date and file type like this : year-month-day_filetype .. except one of them doesn't contain day ( year-month_filetype ) [-you can see the picture -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRoer.png) .. I need to delete that one doesn't contain day .. please help .. many thanks

```
private void scanFolder(final String fileTypename, File currentFolder, File outputFolder) {
    System.out.println("Scanning folder [" + currentFolder + "]...");
    File[] files = currentFolder.listFiles(filter);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            scanFolder(fileTypename, file, outputFolder);
        } else {
            copy(file, outputFolder);
        }
    }
    for (File f : outputFolder.listFiles()) {
        if (f.getName().contains("CW")) {
            f.delete();
        }
        System.out.println("Processing " + outputFolder.listFiles() + "   Deleted ... ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match your objective.  Deleting a file based on name length and deleting a file based on missing the day are not the same thing.

Comment: thanks for responding to my question ,   I want  to delete that file missing the day .. normally if name missing day it will be the shortest one in the list so we can delete by length of name or missing day ( if by messing day it will be better ) , thanks

Comment: one way to go would be to split the filename on underscore, split element 1 (if it exists, take care not to look beyond the end of the array) on -, then see if you have 3 entries or less.

Comment: Yes but what happens if you have a new type of File that happens to have a shorter name?  Deleting based on length is prone to bugs and is not as scalable, deleting on certain parameters such as the date missing is more likely to work for more cases and not incorrectly delete files.  Decide which one fits your project better.

Comment: thanks again , it will be better for my project  if I can delete file by missing day

Comment: Jeremy Kahan , can you show me how to do that .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you need a function to check if your string is the format you expect but missing the day. This should do the trick.

```
private boolean missingDay(String filename){
    boolean result = false;
    String[] parts = filename.split("_",3);
    if (parts.length == 3){
        String[] dateParts = parts[1].split("-",3);
        if (dateParts.length<3){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you'll say something like:

```
if (f.getName().contains("CW") || missingDay(f.getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void scanFolder(final String fileTypename, File currentFolder, File outputFolder){
        System.out.println("Scanning folder [" + currentFolder + "]...");
        File[] files = currentFolder.listFiles(filter);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                    scanFolder(fileTypename, file, outputFolder); 

                }else { 
                    copy(file, outputFolder);
                } 
            }
                     for (File f : outputFolder.listFiles()) 
                     {
                         if (f.getName().contains("CW") || missingDay(f.getName())){ 
                        f.delete();}
                    System.out.println("Processing " + outputFolder.listFiles() + "   Deleted ... ");
}  
    }        

    private boolean missingDay(String filename){
        boolean result = false;
        String[] parts = filename.split("_",3);
        if (parts.length == 3){
            String[] dateParts = parts[1].split("-",3);
            if (dateParts.length<3){
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```